# Genetic Algorithm Truncation

Tags: java

I am implementing truncation selection method to minimize a function. I need to calculate the fitness of each individual and sort the individuals according to their fitness. 
I create an array of class Individual. Individual class has a function naming getFitness() which calculates the individual fitness. Truncation class sort the Individuals based on their fitness.
I pass a reference variable of class Individual to Truncation which sorts the individuals. Then I call the getFitness() function to get the fitness.
The problem is that I am not getting the sorted individuals. 
I am posting my code. If anyone can please sort out the problem.
Thank you

```
public class Individual {

Random random=new Random();

int max=10;
int min=-5;

double x1;
double x2;
double fitness;
double term1;
double term2;

public void Initialize()
{
    x1=random.nextDouble()*(max-min)+min;
    x2=random.nextDouble()*(max-min)+min;
}

public void printValues()
{
    System.out.printf("\nx1=%f\tx2=%f",x1,x2);
}

public double getFitness()
{   
    term1=100* (Math.pow(x1,2)-x2);
    term2= Math.pow(1-x1,2);
    fitness=term1+term2;
    return fitness;
}

public void printFitness()
{
    System.out.printf("\nFitness=%f",fitness);
}

}

public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int pop_size=5;
    Individual ind[]=new Individual[pop_size];
    double fitness[]=new double[pop_size];
    Truncation truncation=new Truncation();

    //initializing individual values
    for(int i=0;i<pop_size;i++)
    {
        ind[i]= new Individual();
        ind[i].Initialize();
    }

    //calculating individual fitness
    for(int i=0;i<pop_size;i++)
    {
        fitness[i]=ind[i].getFitness();
        ind[i].printFitness();
        //ind[i].printValues();
    }

    //using truncation selection to sort individuals
    truncation.Selection(ind,pop_size);

    System.out.printf("\n\n");

    //printing sorted fitness
    for(int i=0;i<pop_size;i++)
    {
        fitness[i]=ind[i].getFitness();
        ind[i].printFitness();
        //ind[i].printValues();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: What is your Java problem? StackOverflow is not an application debugging service, you need to ask a specific and answerable question. This is neither, "please sort out the problem" is not a question.

Comment: I think the problem is on line 253 of the `Truncation` class.  Or maybe it's on line 16.  Or maybe line 73.  Or possibly some other line.  Since I have no idea what any of those lines look like, anything I guess will be as good as anything else.

Comment: I just want to pass Individual array to Truncation class, make changes and print the values of Individual class after making changes

Comment: @user3367327 Fine.  You did.  So what's your question?